# Error when defining new environment

Tags: errors, xetex, environments

I'm trying to use the `\newenvironment` command under XeLaTeX with the `fontspec` and `polyglossia` packages, and it seems that the closing commands of the new environment is not recognized. How can I make it work?

Here's a minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tamil}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\texttamil}{Nirmala UI}
\newenvironment{Tam}{\begin{texttamil}}{\end{texttamil}}

\begin{document}
text in Times 1
\begin{texttamil}
உடல் text in Nirmala 1
\end{texttamil}
text in Times 2
\Tam{உடல் text in Nirmala 2}
text in Times 3
\end{document}
```

"text in Times 3" is not correctly displayed since it remains in Nirmala. I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{texttamil} on input line 18 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.20 \end{document}

?
[1] (Default.aux) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 18 (\begingroup)
### bottom levelstdin -> Default.pdf
[1]
27625 bytes written
```

I'm using Windows 10, Miktex and Texmaker.

Comment: You define `Tam` as an environment, but then use it as a macro: why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `\newenvironment{Tam}{...x...}{...y...}`, you should use

```
\begin{Tam}
<text>
\end{Tam}
```

not `\Tam{<text>}`.

Don't use `\begin{texttamil}` either.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tamil}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\texttamil}{Tamil Sangam MN} % the one I have
\newenvironment{Tam}
  {\texttamil\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

text in Times 1
{\texttamil உடல் text in Nirmala 1}
text in Times 2
\begin{Tam}
உடல் text in Nirmala 2
\end{Tam}
text in Times 3

\end{document}
```

[image]